# IllegalStateException: Fragment YoutubeLessonFragment not attached to a context

Tags: android, android-context, android-youtube-api

I am using `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` in one of my fragments but I am not using it inside the layout file but initialising it programmatically. Some of the users are facing this crash at runtime:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment YoutubeLessonFragment{3a2e875} not attached to a context.
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.requireContext(Fragment.java:614)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:678)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getString(Fragment.java:700)
       at com.musicmuni.riyaz.youtubelesson.YoutubeLessonFragment.loadYoutubeVideo(YoutubeLessonFragment.java:168)
       at com.musicmuni.riyaz.youtubelesson.YoutubeLessonPresenter$2.onModuleLoaded(YoutubeLessonPresenter.java:188)
       at com.musicmuni.riyaz.data.AppDataRepositoryImpl$10.run(AppDataRepositoryImpl.java:187)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6221)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

My code for initialising the youtube fragment goes like this:

```
private YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youtubePlayerFrag;
.........
    public void loadYoutubeVideo(String videoId) {
            mVideoId = videoId;
            if(getContext() != null) {
                youtubePlayerFrag = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
                youtubePlayerFrag.initialize(getString(R.string.youtube_api_developer_key),
                        this);
                getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.flYoutubeVideoHolder,
                        youtubePlayerFrag).commit();
            }
        }
```

where `loadYoutubeVideo(...)` gets a callback from a background running thread loading the required video id. Any pointers here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably your `Fragment` in not attached to the `activity` while you are calling `getString()` method.

because the docs says:

> Fragments now have requireContext(), requireActivity(), requireHost(),
>   and requireFragmentManager() methods, which return a NonNull object of
>   the equivalent get methods or throw an IllegalStateException.

You might want to check if the fragment is attached to the activity or not, by calling `isAdded()` method of fragment.

Also you can pass the argument directly to `newInstance(..args..)` rather that creating `initialise()` method.

Comment: okay.. can I use `getContext() != null` check instead of `isAdded()` check ?

Comment: 'isAdded()' is different. 'getContext()' will never return null if 'isAdded()' return true. While inverse is not true.